Does the Railcard discount apply when going to / from Heathrow on the Elizabeth line?
I have a National Railcard which gives me a 33% discount on the Tube, DLR, London Overground, Elizabeth line in off-peak hours. Does this discount apply when taking the Elizabeth line from Heathrow in off-peak hours? If yes, does the discount apply to the price including the 7.30 GBP surcharge or is the surcharge applied in full? If not, does it apply on the Piccadilly line from Heathrow?
EDIT: To clarify, it's a 16-25 Railcard, and I have an Oyster card onto which the railcard discount has been loaded.

I suspect the answer is going to be "no", but it would be helpful to know exactly what sort of railcard you have.  I've never come across such a thing as a "National Railcard".

Seems like https://www.network-railcard.co.uk/about-the-railcard/using-your-railcard/

...which says "You cannot buy Network Railcard discounted tickets for journeys wholly on the London Underground and Docklands Light Railway. However discounted tickets bought for cross-London rail journeys which involve travel on the London Underground are permitted." The Elizabeth Line isn't considered part of the Underground but of Crossrail.

Do you have/are you going to get a Oyster card?

Yes, I have an Oyster card and it's a 16-25 Railcard, sorry for not being clear!

For a non-Network Railcard it does apply to the whole journey
You can have a Anytime Day Single between Heathrow rail and Zone 1 for £8.10 as opposed to £12.30 without a railcard
Note that it is 60p cheaper to get a paper ticket compared to using a Oyster card with a registered railcard discount off-peak
On peak, since the ticket can be a Anytime (no off-peak restrictions), it is a lot cheaper (compared to £13.30) to use a paper ticket against Oyster again in the Peak time frames.

If you have a Oyster PAYG Card with your discount loaded, it will also apply to the tube lowering the cost from £5.6 to £3.65

Your Anytime Day Single link above is applying a Young Person's Railcard discount, not a Network Railcard discount.  It may be that the OP has a YNG, not an NEW, but we'll need him/her to tell us.

@MadHatter Editted the intro

Occasionally I try to understand UK train pricing. Answers like this remind me it is pointless to try. Hats off to those who do.

I have a 16-25 Railcard and it's loaded on an Oyster card, so it's 3.65 on the Piccadilly and 8.10 on the Elizabeth, right?

@kmf 3.65 on the Pic yes, for the EL it's either 8.6 on Oyster or 8.10 on paper tickets

If this railcard is a Network Railcard, the answer is "not really".
The Network Railcard is not valid on Oyster PAYG journeys, or services wholly on London Underground, so you couldn't use it on the Piccadilly Line from Heathrow.  You can use it against an Elizabeth Line service, but the minimum fare of £13 for all adult journeys Mon-Fri means that, unless it's a weekend, the discount will be fairly minimal.

No such product? Please see National Railcards issued by National Rail, although it offers actual cards of the same types as other vendors.

@WeatherVane Weirdly enough, the area-limited Network railcard is actually counted as a National Railcard

@WeatherVane then you might as well say "piece of cardboard", since all the railcards are members of the class "pieces of cardboard" (yes, I know; forget the digital ones for a moment).  Yet not all pieces of cardboard offer similar discount structure on rail tickets.  I repeat my assertion that there is no single thing called a national railcard, and unless we know which member of the class of products collectively referred to as "national railcards" the OP has, it's no easier to answer than if the OP says (s)he has a piece of cardboard.

I apologize for lack of clarity, I specified it's a 16-25 Railcard. I'm used to calling it "National Railcard" for some reason, probably because it's how I had it called the first time I learnt about its existence.

@kmf that's brilliant, thank you for that!  Then Nicolas' answer is the right one, and I'm glad to see you've accepted it.  I'll leave mine here, though, if that's OK with you, in case anyone wants to know about Network Railcards.
